# django-mongodb-engine and Django's native auth system

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-authentication, django-mongodb-engine

As stated in the title, I am using `django-mongodb-engine` and I am attempting to configure the native Django authentication framework. I've read some comments online that it should work out of the box sans some features. However, I couldn't find any tutorials and, furthermore, I am getting errors on trying to set it up on my own. The issue I'm having most certainly has to do with database permissions. I have included the Django middleware and apps per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/). However, when I issue the `syncdb` command it fails with an error.

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on MyDB.system.namespaces
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'MyDB',
        'USER': 'mySuperUser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    # some other DBs
}
```

Mongo User Permissions

```
myDB> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "user" : "mySuperUser", "pwd" : "...", "roles" : [   "readWriteAnyDatabase", "userAdminAnyDatabase",         "dbAdminAnyDatabase",   "clusterAdmin" ] }
```

I'm not sure what other permissions I can grant this guy, and/or where else I need to create this user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, here is the solution. You must use the native mongo `admin` database. Thus, the required changes:

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'admin',
        'USER': 'mySuperUser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    # some other DBs
}
```

The user `mySuperUser` must naturally exist on the `admin` database. To be safe regarding authentication actions such as adding and removing users, I gave it the `userAdminAnyDatabase` privilege in mongo. The privileges are probably excessive, but I'd have to play with it to determine the proper scope of the required permissions. Here are the permissions:

```
// mongo
admin> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "pwd" : "...", "roles" : [         "readWriteAnyDatabase",         "dbAdminAnyDatabase",   "clusterAdmin",         "userAdminAnyDatabase" ], "user" : "mySuperUser" }
```

Next, we can finally run the `syncdb` command:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (leave blank to use 'someUser'): 
Email address: someUser@user.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...

Installing indices for admin.LogEntry model.
Installing indices for auth.Group_permissions model.
Installing indices for auth.Group model.
Installing indices for auth.User_groups model.
Installing indices for auth.User_user_permissions model.
Installing indices for auth.User model.
Installing indices for sessions.Session model.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I had not specified a SITE_ID in my settings.py. I did this:

```
./manage.py shell
>>>from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>>Site().save()
>>>Site.objects.all()[0].id
u'5391dbc22ebd1212246d50c4'
```

If you aren't 'django.contrib.sites' then I'm not sure why this would be a problem. Unless you had been using that module and already installed the collection/table to the database. In either case, this is how I got MongoDB to start working correctly again.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue. My Mongo DB is hosted on MongoLab and I don't find any solutions to solve this error. Although that my user already exists in my DB, I don't want to use the `admin` database. Someone else has encountered the same problem or find a solution ?